# Why Can't Bind Wpf DataGrid MaxWidth When it's Parrent is Hidden when Form Loads?

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

i have a DataGrid Inside a Grid that is Hidden when form loads,and want to bind Width of datagrid toit's parrent,but it dosen't seem to get bind,this is the sample:

```
<Grid  Visibility="Binding....}">
    <DataGrid MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid  }}"
  .../>
 .
 .
 </Grid>
```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
AncestorType={x:Type Grid}
```

instead of

```
AncestorType=Grid
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: @ ethicallogics: No,Even when i bind it to a property in the viewmodel it dosen't bind!!i'm sure it's because of Visibility,because when i set Visibility to visible it binds!!!

Comment: Visibility of DataGrid will also be same as Grid. Because DataGrid is child of Grid.

Comment: thanks for your attention,it's just funny,when i bind itself(the Grid.Width) it works,but it's child can't get binding!!!i realy don't Know why?!

Comment: I don't know Why you trying this and what is the need .Because if you don't specify any Width or MaxWidth to DataGrid.It automatically will have same Width/MaxWidth as that of Grid(if there is only one column in the grid.).

Comment: @ ethicallogics: i know that!!but i want to know what's this binding issue?!(and i let u know why i need this;i have a scrollViewer and as you know when you put a datagrid with coulmn widths=* inside a scrollViewer ,and set the scrollViewer's  HorizentalScroolBarVisibility=atuo.then the datatgrid columns spread too mutch!so you need to set MaxWidht for that.(sorry for my bad english:))

Comment: simplest solution to this is set MaxWidth of Grid say MaxWidth="500" instead of Datagrid.

Comment: thanks,but i need too find the right solution,i don't want to bypass it!!thank you anyway:)